# How to create UIAlertViewController like Whatsapp or Facebook Messanger Alert popup in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I want to present UIAlertViewController like Whatsapp or Facebook Messanger Alert poup.

1. Alert popup in Whatsapp.

[image]

2. Alert popup in Facebook Messanger
   [image]

**Please help me to create Alert like this.**

Comment: WhatsApp's looks like a custom control. Facebook's is a [Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contextmenu(menuitems:)).

Comment: But it is a part of SwiftUI not in Swift

Comment: SwiftUI is written using swift... so you want UIKit?

Comment: Yes, I want in UIKit

Answer (score 0):

I done something like WhatsApp popover so I mention its steps.

for animation purposes I use this framework
https://github.com/corin8823/Popover

And This is how you can use it :-

```
 func homeProfileBtn(){
        let aView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width / 4, height: 111))
        let buttonStackView = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 15, width: aView.frame.size.width, height: 100))
        
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Profile", for: .normal)
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let button2 = UIButton()
        button2.setTitle("Help", for: .normal)
        button2.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button2.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button2.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let button4 = UIButton()
        button4.setTitle("Full Access", for: .normal)
        button4.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button4.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button4.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button4.addTarget(self, action: #selector(openWebview), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let button3 = UIButton()
        button3.setTitle("Log out", for: .normal)
        button3.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        button3.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)
        button3.titleLabel?.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
        button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(logout), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        buttonStackView.axis = .vertical
        buttonStackView.alignment = .fill
        buttonStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        buttonStackView.spacing = 0.0
        
        buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
        buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button2)
        buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button4)
        buttonStackView.addArrangedSubview(button3)
        aView.addSubview(buttonStackView)
        
        popover.show(aView, fromView: sender)
    }
```

NOTE:- I added UIButtons in the popover if you want to do same like you shown in image then you can use UIView or UITableView

Answer (score 0):

After all I found a beautiful Cocoapods to present UIAlert like Whatsapp or Messanger in Swift using UIKit

Cocoapods : https://github.com/GitHawkApp/ContextMenu

```
@IBAction func onButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
  ContextMenu.shared.show(
    sourceViewController: self,
    viewController: MyContentViewController(),
    sourceView: sender
  )
}
```

```
ContextMenu.shared.show(
  sourceViewController: self,
  viewController: MenuViewController(),
  options: ContextMenu.Options(containerStyle: ContextMenu.ContainerStyle(backgroundColor: .blue)),
  sourceView: button
)
```

```
ContextMenu.shared.show(
  sourceViewController: self,
  viewController: MyContentViewController()
)
```

```
class MyContentViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "Demo"
    preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 200)
  }
}
```

Using this Pod

```
pod 'ContextMenu'
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a very classy method to achieve this menu in swift.
But it will work iOS-13 and upper versions.

Here I have Rows and Section on my TableView. you can change or customise this code according to your requirements.

```
// TableView cellForRowAt Code.

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ReceiverCell", for: indexPath) as! ReceiverCell

    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        // contentView : it could be any view which you want to Highlight. just use that view.
        let interaction = UIContextMenuInteraction(delegate: self)
        cell.contentView.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.contentView.superview?.tag = indexPath.section
        cell.contentView.addInteraction(interaction)
    }

    return cell
}
```

Now, Write and implement Delegate methods of It.
Create an Extension of your Controller. Here I used UIViewController as default controller.

```
// UIViewController Extension.

// MARk: - Context Menu & Action Sheet
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension UIViewController: UIContextMenuInteractionDelegate {

    func contextMenuInteraction(_ interaction: UIContextMenuInteraction, configurationForMenuAtLocation location: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        guard let superviewTag = interaction.view?.superview?.tag, let interactionTag = interaction.view?.tag else { return nil }
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration(identifier: "anyIdentifier" as NSCopying, previewProvider: nil, actionProvider: { _ in
            let contextMenu = self.getContextMenu(data: "Copy this data")
            return UIMenu(title: "", children: [contextMenu])
        })
    }

    func getContextMenu(data: String) -> UIMenu {
        let copyAction = UIAction(title: "Copy", image: UIImage(named: "icon_copy", in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil)) { _ in
            UIPasteboard.general.string = data
        }

        let editImageAction = UIAction(title: "Edit", image: UIImage(named: "edit_icon", in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil)) { _ in
            // Edit message
        }

        let infoAction = UIAction(title: "Info", image: UIImage(named: "Info_icon", in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)) { _ in
            // write info code here.
        }

        let replyAction = UIAction(title: "Reply", image: UIImage(named: "reply", in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil)) { _ in
            // Write reply code here.
        }

        let deleteAction = UIAction(title: "Delete", image: UIImage(named: "icon_delete", in: Bundle.main, compatibleWith: nil), attributes: .disabled) { _ in
            // Delete message goes here
        }

        return UIMenu(title: "", options: .displayInline, children: [copyAction, editImageAction, infoAction, replyAction, deleteAction])
    }

}
```

Everything is done now. Run your code and Long press on any tableView cell. you will see the magic.